# How to select row where one value also contains in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let Say Table A

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Jon | 23 |
| Lili | 43 |

Let Say Table B

| Name | Car |
| --- | --- |
| jon | bmw |
| maya | mercedes |

I need exact 1 row of Table A where name also contains in Table B. Names in B are all lowercase.

What I tried:

```
select lower(name) from tableA intesects select lower(name) from tableB LIMIT 1;
```

But this gave me only name value not entire row (name, age)

For Jon I need as result.

| Jon | 23 |

because Jon is also contained in tableB as lowerCase.

Comment: Sounds like you need a subquery. To be sure, please add the expected results from the given dataset

Answer (score 2):

Use an EXISTS condition:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where exists (select * 
              from tableb b
              where lower(a.name) = lower(b.name));
```